# Adding up variable within loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I got a number of files and I need to determine how many of those will fit on a 4Tb drive by just knowing first filename. Name pattern is `001j00_rf_geo_????$seqn` with sequential 3-digit number at the end. Say I start with `001j00_rf_geo_????100`.

```
block=4000000000000
shopt -s dotglob
seqn="100"
size=`stat -c%s 001j00_rf_geo_????$seqn`
for (( i=$size ;i < $block ; seqn++ ))
    do
    ((size+=$(stat -c%s 001j00_rf_geo_????$seqn)))
done
echo $size
```

I am pretty sure the summing up part in `for` loop is wrong. I just could get my head around how to get a total size of files having the the loop part in code.

Comment: How about `for ((; size < block; seqn++))` or `while ((size < block)); do ... ((seqn++)); done`  You are not using `i` at all -- you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `for` loop, you are not using `'i'` at all -- it is unneeded. If you want to use a C-style `for` loop, you can simply omit the initializer:

```
for ((; size < block; seqn++))
do
```

or use a `while` loop instead

```
while ((size < block))
do
    ... 
    ((seqn++))
done
```

Of course you can just move your initialization to the `for` loop as well and get rid of the one above

```
for ((seqn = 100; size < block; seqn++))
do
```

Give either a try and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.

Comment: Sure, glad to help... and don't worry, you will still have many opportunities to beat your head into a wall over something similar... we all do it `:)`